# Should I separate my table?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a question about my DB design.

I want to save some information about province and the country. At the first I thought that I can save all of this information in one table (`General_info`). Then for each record in this table; values of columns, which belongs to country should be repeated.

Another idea is to separate this table into two tables (`General_info_country` and `general_info_province`). The first table with only 3 columns and the other with more than 10.

What should I do? Which approach is more efficient?

Comment: Is this a lookup table? Is it likely to change? Do you need to use country information separately from province information?

Comment: Could you show your two sample designs? I'm finding it hard to visualize what you're asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue with the first approach (one big table) is that if any one country information changes, you need to update multiple rows, meaning you might make a mistake and end up with inconsistent information.

The second approach is normalized and considered a better relational design.

Answer (score 0):

If the relation is one to one and will remain one to one, then you can go both ways.
But if it is one to many then of course you must split them, and have the foreign key in the many part

In the case where the relation is one to one the question becomes, how frequent are you going to use the all of the attributes ?

If you are going to use both tables together frequently then i suggest you do not split them because you are going to need to join them a lot in your queries.

But if you are going to be using the 2 tales alone rather then using the info from both tables together then splitting them could save you some time.